# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider in which I am using links `<a id="foo" class="oslide">Chineese Food</a>` as a way to navigate the slider. In order for the navigation to work I needed to add `a.href = "#";` to the link's click function like so:

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
    a.href = "#"; 
}
```

This works great, however, in the console each time I click a link with the  `a.href = "#";` I get the error **Uncaught Reference error: a is not defined**. I tried using `$('a[href*="#"]');` and also adding the `href` attribute to the anchor tag. Both solutions break the slide's navigation. How do I resolve this?

Comment: replace `a` with `this`

Comment: Uhm, so where is `a` coming from, if that's the only code, it's clearly not defined ?

Comment: so why does it work at all?

Comment: what do you mean it works?  It doesn't throw an error on load, because the code hasn't executed yet.  But when you click the link, the code executes, thereby throwing the a is not defined error.

Comment: i am using visual studio. when I typed `a.` it gave me href as an option. nothing was underlined. I figured it was ok to use. Thanks for your time and assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does it work great if you get an error each time?

The error is telling you what the problem is: `a` is not defined as a variable, and yet you're trying to access it. The actual `<a>` object that the event is bound to can be accessed using `this` as such:

```
this.href = '#';
```

Comment: I can't tell you whether or not it works without knowing what the intended behavior is.

Comment: The links on the slider navigates the slider's content from one slide to the next(like navigation dots on any jQuery slider). The `"#"` value is used in the link to tell the script to fire a change based on the id of what link the `#` was fired from

Comment: I assume you're using some kind of 3rd party library to implement that slider. In that case it still works because the library is still working as it's supposed to. Either that, or there's a significant amount of code that you haven't shared with us, because `this.href = '#'` certainly would not do what you're describing on its own

Comment: the latter of the two. I have been working very hard to learn javascript and not use 3rd party tools.

Comment: I do, however, follow tutorials, and enjoy forking code :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('href','#')
});
```